# Emulating 64 bit OS in a 32 bit host using VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible to emulate a 64 bit operation system (such as CentOS 6) in VirtualBox in a Linux Mint 32 bit host?

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't emulate an OS, it runs a real OS.  (It emulates some hardware, such as a mouse, keyboard, and SATA controller, to provide the hardware environment that the OS depends on.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

[According to their manual.](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host operating systems,[[11](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#ftn.idp6247488)]provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see the section called “[Hardware vs. software virtualization](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt)”).
>
> You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
>
> If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.
>
> On 64-bit hosts (which typically come with hardware virtualization support), 64-bit guest operating systems are always supported regardless of settings, so you can simply install a 64-bit operating system in the guest.
>
> > **Warning**
> >
> > On any host, you should enable the I/O APIC for virtual machines that you intend to use in 64-bit mode. This is especially true for 64-bit Windows VMs. See the section called “["Advanced" tab](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-general-advanced)”. In addition, for 64-bit Windows guests, you should make sure that the VM uses the Intel networking device, since there is no 64-bit driver support for the AMD PCNet card; see the section called “[Virtual networking hardware](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nichardware)”.
>
> If you use the "Create VM" wizard of the VirtualBox graphical user interface (see the section called “[Creating your first virtual machine](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm)”), VirtualBox will automatically use the correct settings for each selected 64-bit operating system type.

Comment: as long as you have a 64-bit processor

Comment: @BroScience Correct.

Comment: But note the restrictions.

Comment: @JulianKnight Hence the link.  I'll edit them in.

Comment: @Kruug: good man!