# Issue with installing Kali Linux on virtualbox as a virtualmachine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux, kernel

While trying to install Kali Linux as a virtual machine on Virtualbox I received an error saying "An error was returned while trying to install the kernel into the target system". I am unable to figure out what is causing this issue. Could you please tell me what might be causing this problem. Here is the screenshot of the virtual machine for more details. https://preview.redd.it/v9a756vnqp651.png?width=1366&format=png&auto=webp&s=417a143798439af695a9be5c625399a676b32272 --- link of the screenshot

Edit: I am running the VM on a 64-bit host and the disk image of kali Linux is 64 bit too. I got windows 98 to work on it a few days ago.

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the virtual console 4 if it helps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzrTn.png

Edit: Here is a link to the VBox.log file if it helps: https://gist.github.com/chesskinger1/1f1cdf453b16bdb9b85841294d5ae6ed

Edit : I redid the installation and this time a different error occured for some reason. It says an error was returned while trying to install the initramfs tools package onto the target system. Could anybody tell what is causing these errors.

Edit : Dosent matter, I downloaded the ova file and now it is working fine

Comment: May need more details. Are you running on a 32-bit host, or a VM that's acting as if it has a 32-bit processor? Have you gotten any other VM working to prove the VBox install itself isn't the problem? [Possibly relevant answer](https://superuser.com/a/557892/928285) about running a 64-bit guest on a 32-bit host.

Comment: I am running the vm on a 64 bit host and the disk image of kali linux is 64 bit too. I got windows 98 to work on it a few days ago.

Comment: Windows 98 is 32-bit. In BIOS, did you turn ON Hardware Virtualization and VT-x?  You need to do this. I have Kali V2020 64-bit running here so it does work in the correct environment.

Comment: Yes hardware virtualizatrion is turned on.

Comment: And VT-x ?  You need both. If it is, try downloading another ISO file for Kali. Use the full version, and try installing again.

Comment: What I thought both hardware virtualization and vtx were the same things. I have only enabled the vtx. Going to see the option for hardware virtualization.

Comment: Wait they are the same things. On the internet enable virtualization is referred to as VT-x, so it is already enabled.

Comment: By the way I have downloaded the Kali Linux 64-Bit Installer from the kali linux official site. It is the first link from the top with a size of 3.6 GB. Do I have to download the Kali Linux 64-Bit Live version?

Comment: You wrote "I have downloaded the Kali Linux 64-Bit Installer from the kali linux official site. It is the first link from the top with a size of 3.6 GB."  I used this version and have it running. Try a brand new Virtual Machine with this 3.6GB ISO file.

Answer (score 2):

I banged my head against the wall here for hours as well.

Turns out, Offensive Security (the guys developing Kali Linux) provide their own VirtualBox machines for download at [their website](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/). Select your preferred virtual machine platform (VMware or VirtualBox) and download the virtual machine directly. Hope this helps!